# How to detect 3rd party keyboard in react native (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In native iOS we can specify shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier to disable 3rd party keyboard.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier
{

    if (extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

In android is there a solution? Managed to use InputMethodManager to detect custom/3rd party keyboard and prompt a message but can’t find a way to disable it or change it back to the factory/manufacturer default keyboard.

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials, or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can’t find a way to disable it or change it back to the factory/manufacturer default keyboard

That is not possible. In Android, the choice of input method is up to the user (under the control of the OS), not apps.

In particular, the "factory/manufacturer default keyboard" may be unsuitable for the user for a variety of reasons, including:

- Language support
- Motor impairment
- Visual impairment